# Sending mail using javamail throws error

Tags: java, android, smtp, imap, jakarta-mail

I have two activities, one for recieving emails using Imap  the second is to send email using SMTP. The  button for send email activity is inside the Recieve Email activity, So the Recieve Email Activity has to run before Send Email ACitivty..

My problem is I keep getting an Exception saying 
`Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 25` at `Transport.send(new_message)`

However, if I run the same activity without calling the recieve email activity first, then it works without any problem.
Can someone help me as to why this happens?

Here's the Code for 
RecieveEmail Async task (the full Activity code is too long)

```
 try{


               Properties props = new Properties();
               props.setProperty( "mail.imaps.socketFactory.class", "com.X509TrustAll.DummySSLSocketFactory" );
               Log.v("EmailList", "Stting properties");

              // Get the default Session object.
              session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
              Log.v("EmailList", "Geting Default Instance");

              // Get a Store object that implements the specified protocol.
              store = session.getStore("imaps");
              Log.v("EmailList", "Getting Sesion");

              //Connect to the current host using the specified username and password.
              Log.v("EmailList", "Connecting...");
              store.connect(host,port, user, password);
              Log.v("EmailList", "Connected");

              //Create a Folder object corresponding to the given name.
              Folder[] folders = store.getDefaultFolder().list("*");
              Log.v("EmailList", "Got Folder List");
              folder =  folders[5];



              // Open the Folder.
              Log.v("EmailList", "Opening Folder");
              folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

              Log.v("EmailList", "Getting Messages");
              messages = folder.getMessages();

              Log.v("EmailList", "Got Messages");


          } catch (Exception e){

              Log.v("EmailList", "Exception");

          }
        }

              for (int i = lastMessageNumber -1;  i >= interateUpto; i--) {

                  Log.v("EmailRecieve", "Email no. " + Integer.toString(i));

                  javax.mail.Address[] froms = messages[i].getFrom();
                  String emailAdress = froms == null ? null : ((InternetAddress) froms[0]).getAddress();


                  FromAsync.add(emailAdress);

                  SubjectAsync.add(messages[i].getSubject());

                  SentDateAsync.add(messages[i].getSentDate().toString());


                  Part part = messages[i];

                  checkAttachments(part);



                  if (messages[i].isSet(Flag.SEEN)){

                      SeenAsync.add("true");

                  }else{

                      SeenAsync.add("false");

                  }


              }



              lastMessageNumber = lastMessageNumber - 19;   //new last number is stored

              folder.close(false);
              store.close();

        } catch (Exception e){

                  Log.v("EmailList", "Exception");

        }



      Log.v("EmailList", "Retrieve Email Finished");



        return null;

    }
```

And Here's the code for Send Email (again the full code is too long so I'm only posting whats relevant, i.e UI  etc. are not posted

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        //Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
          String to = To.getText().toString();

          // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
          String from = "foobar@foobar.hehe";

          // The Host
          String smtphost = "www.isleworthsyon.hounslow.sch.uk";

          // Get system properties
          Properties smtpproperties = System.getProperties();

          // Setup mail server
          smtpproperties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", smtphost);

          // Get the default Session object.
          Session smtpsession = Session.getDefaultInstance(smtpproperties);

          try{
             MimeMessage new_message = new MimeMessage(smtpsession);

             // Set From:
             new_message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

             // Set To:
             new_message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                                      new InternetAddress(to));

             // Set Subject: 
             new_message.setSubject(Subject.getText().toString());

             if (hasAttachment == true){

                 // Create the message part 
                 BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

                 // Fill the message
                 messageBodyPart.setText(Body.getText().toString());

                 // Create a multipar message
                 Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

                 // Set text message part
                 multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

                 // Iterating over all Attachments    
                 for (int i=0; i < attachmentFiles.size(); i++){

                    if (attachmentFiles.get(i).equals("null") != true)    {

                         messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
                         String filename = attachmentFiles.get(i);
                         FileDataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
                         messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
                         messageBodyPart.setFileName(source.getName());
                         multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

                    }
                 }


                 new_message.setContent(multipart);

             }else{

                 // Set Body if not attaching anything
                 new_message.setText(Body.getText().toString());

             }

             // Send message
             Transport.send(new_message);
             sendingSuccesfull = true;
          }catch (MessagingException mex) {
             sendingSuccesfull = false;
             Log.v("Email Compose", "Message Sending Failed, Details: " + mex.getMessage());

          }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: `localhost` is the phone itself. Has that a running mailserver?

Comment: @zapl well it should be because I can send mails with the same code if i dont call 'Recieve Email' Activity first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try cleaning up [these common mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes) and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: this is more of a comment than an answer, but you were right!! Thank you.

Comment: It was the getDefaultInstance that was causing the problem, because when I call that, it pulls the same session from EmailRecieve Activity , hence transport.send() failed. Session.getInstance creates a new session everytime and solves the problem